# Console.log shows an Object initially, then shows an Array of one object upon click

Tags: reactjs, typescript, console.log, mobx, mobx-react

I call an observable in my React component using MobX. When I console log that observable, the console shows the value first as an Object, then when I click on it, it transforms into an Array on that one object. Let me show it with images:

First like this:
[image: Console log shows Object]

Then as an array upon click:
[image: Console log now shows an array]

If I click again to close it, it becomes object again.

It's like Schrodinger's cat.

My observable is defined as:

```js
@observable anecdote: IAnecdote | undefined = undefined
```

My action that fills in the anecdote observable is like this:

```js
    @action loadAnecdote = async (slug: string) => {
        this.loadingInitial = true
        try {
            const anecdote = await agent.Anecdotes.selected(slug)
            runInAction(() => {
                this.anecdote = anecdote
                this.loadingInitial = false
            })
            return anecdote
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

I observed that if I define the return type of `await agent.Anecdotes.selected(slug)` as a `Promise<IAnecdote>`, then the result also becomes inconsistent. Otherwise, if its type is `any`, I can use the result as an array of one object, as seen in below code `result[0]`.

Because of this inconsistency, I cannot use the observable anecdote. Instead of that I return the direct result of fetching. And as seen in the component below, I assign that result to a ref. That is the only way I can get this code to work.

```js
interface DetailParams {
    slug: string
}

const AnecdoteDetails: React.FC<RouteComponentProps<DetailParams>> = ({match}) => {
    const rootStore = useContext(RootStoreContext)
    const { loadAnecdote, anecdote, loadingInitial } = rootStore.anecdoteStore
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const ref = useRef(anecdote)

    useEffect(() => {
        loadAnecdote(match.params.slug)
            .then(result => ref.current = result[0])
            .then(() => {
                setLoading(true); 
                document.title = parse(ref.current!.title.rendered).toString()
            })
        
    }, [loadAnecdote, match.params.slug, setLoading])

    if(loadingInitial || !loading) return <LoadingComponent content='Anecdote loading...' />

    return (
        <Fragment>
            {loading &&
                <Fragment>
                    <AnecdoteListItem anecdote={ref.current!} />
                    <AnecdoteComment anecdoteId={ref.current!.id} />
                </Fragment>
            }
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default observer(AnecdoteDetails)
```

What can I do to remove this inconsistency and directly use anecdote observable instead of ref.current inside the component?

Comment: This is not an object, but an array with a single element `[ Object ] -> [ {...} ]`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't mind the squared brackets. Now it's revealed to me. Silly mistake :)

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg please, repost your comment as an answer if you think it is correct so everybody could know that original question is answered and problem is resolved https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat

Answer (score 0):

This is not an object, but an array with a single element `[ Object ] -> [ {...} ]`